# Playing a sound from a generated buffer in a Windows phone app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, sdk

I new in windows phone sdk.
I can't find example of playing a sound from a generated buffer in a Windows phone app.
Help pls.

i found this example:

```
byte] buffer = new byte[44100 * 2 * 5];

float t = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 44100 * 2 * 5; i += 2)
{
short val = (short)(Math.Sin(t * 2 * Math.PI * 440) * short.MaxValue);
buffer[i] = (byte)(val & 0xFF);
buffer[i + 1] = (byte)(val >> 8);
t += 1 / 44100.0f;
}

sf = new SoundEffect(buffer, 44100, AudioChannels.Mono);

// Play.
sf.Play();
```

but it's crash with error
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195053.aspx

Comment: Need to use  SoundEffect class.  but i need example for start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `FrameworkDispatcher.Update`.

(See exception:
FrameworkDispatcher.Update has not been called. Regular FrameworkDispatcher.Update calls are necessary for fire and forget sound effects and framework events to function correctly. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=193853 for details.)

Set up a timer in your constructor:

```
        var dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick);
        dt.Start();
```

And a Tick event handler:

```
    void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
    }
```

Should work with for example a play button in your app. I have also added one line to your code: `var soundInstance = sf.CreateInstance();`

```
    private void appBarPlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[44100 * 2 * 5];

        float t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 44100 * 2 * 5; i += 2)
        {
            short val = (short)(Math.Sin(t * 2 * Math.PI * 440) * short.MaxValue);
            buffer[i] = (byte)(val & 0xFF);
            buffer[i + 1] = (byte)(val >> 8);
            t += 1 / 44100.0f;
        }

        var sf = new SoundEffect(buffer, 44100, AudioChannels.Mono);
        var soundInstance = sf.CreateInstance();

        // Play.
        sf.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have another problem. If i try to play high frequency tone like 18000hz for example(440 -> 18000) It's play low frequencies, i hear their. What can be a problem? simpleRate 44100.