# Playing buffer, windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I try to play audio buffer in windows phone app.

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[44100 * 2 * 5];

        float t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 44100 * 2 * 5; i += 2)
        {
            short val = (short)(Math.Sin(t * 2 * Math.PI * 440) * short.MaxValue);
            buffer[i] = (byte)(val & 0xFF);
            buffer[i + 1] = (byte)(val >> 8);
            t += 1 / 44100.0f;
        }

        sf = new SoundEffect(buffer, 44100, AudioChannels.Mono);

        // Play.
        sf.Play();
```

i get error: 
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Help pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `FrameworkDispatcher.Update`.

Same answer as here should work:
[Playing a sound from a generated buffer in a Windows phone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697904/playing-a-sound-from-a-generated-buffer-in-a-windows-phone-app/26712854#26712854)